# Showing error in ZF 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I am using ZfcUser (https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) module with ZF2. I am logged in using facebook.After log in I am getting below error.

Fatal error: Call to a member function getEmail() on a non-object in D:\php\htdocs\zend_test\module\Dom\view\dom\dom\index.phtml on line 2

The code exists on line 2

```
<?php echo $this->gravatar($this->zfcUserIdentity()->getEmail()) ?>
```

Could anyone say where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Apparently zfcUserIdentity() doesn't contain a user object. That's the root cause, why it's not the case, that's something for you to figure out ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should always check if the user is logged in. Because otherwise

```
$this->zfcUserIdentity()
```

returns null. This is to avoid an error.
To check if the user is logged in type

```
<?php if(!$this->zfcUserIdentity()) {
    echo $this->gravatar($this->zfcUserIdentity()->getEmail());
} ?>
```

The reason you're not logged is probably in the facebook login implementation.

[Source](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/wiki/How-to-check-if-the-user-is-logged-in)